# Requesting list of a users microhone and headset & phone devices

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, mobile-devices

The audio, video conferencing devices, microhones headset and other devices which are used for microsoft team calls and conferences,    where are thisdata is stored?

How can I request a list for this devices overall users or for  a special user. Is an intune -license needed for that  or are there other ways to request this information e.g. with a graph api call?

Updated 04.10.2021:
I know it is possible to get call records after end calls  and from this i get the device informations. **That is  not my question.**
I would know if there is a possibility to request the devivices a user has connected in the past.

So is there a way to get the infos of connected audio, video devices independend from a ended call.
Because i have no available intune license ,  i don't know if intune only manage client devices  or other devices like audio and video devices too. so that was the reason I mention intune.

But my question is:
Is there a way with graph api or different api to get the connected or registered audio video devices on azure for a user identified with UPN (not locally with running command line tools for requesting audio video devices from the locally device manager).

Comment: Could you please check on below documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I know that i can get the call device from a call record which  i can get with webbhook notifications.
**If you read the 2nd paragraph of my post you should see that this was not my question**  .
I will modify the post more clear for fast reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, we do not have such API available to get the list of devices, using which user has connected in the past.